# yHat's dimensions are changing after feeding the model with test data and loss keep incresing

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, logistic-regression, matrix-multiplication

I am building a logistic regression model for a binary classification problem. At below, you can find my function that performs the forward propagation part and it comprised of activation function and derivative of activation function. The activation function is not a mainstream function, it is a custom one.

My problem is, when I feed this model with my train dataset, everything is okay. After optimization is done, I am feeding the model with test dataset and something weird happening. The yHat variable dimensions are changing. When I use train data, shape of A is `(1000, ))`, but when I use test data, yhat becomes `(1, 200)` but it should be `(200, ))`. Because of this I can not compare it with the original labels since it is `(200, ))`

Also, my loss value is always incresing. I tried to set hyper parameters but in best scenario, loss is staying constant at 0.51...

Here is the output:

```
('Train X shape: ', (2, 1000))
('Train Y shape: ', (1000,))
('Train W shape: ', (2,))
('Train Z shape: ', (1000,))
('Train A shape: ', (1000,))
Loss after iteration 1: 0.500000
-----------------------------------------------------
('Train X shape: ', (2, 1000))
('Train Y shape: ', (1000,))
('Train W shape: ', (2,))
('Train Z shape: ', (1000,))
('Train A shape: ', (1000,))
Loss after iteration 2: 0.546685
-----------------------------------------------------
('Train X shape: ', (2, 1000))
('Train Y shape: ', (1000,))
('Train W shape: ', (2,))
('Train Z shape: ', (1000,))
('Train A shape: ', (1000,))
Loss after iteration 3: 0.627727
-----------------------------------------------------
('Train X shape: ', (2, 1000))
('Train Y shape: ', (1000,))
('Train W shape: ', (2,))
('Train Z shape: ', (1000,))
('Train A shape: ', (1000,))
Loss after iteration 4: 0.758092
-----------------------------------------------------
('Train X shape: ', (2, 1000))
('Train Y shape: ', (1000,))
('Train W shape: ', (2,))
('Train Z shape: ', (1000,))
('Train A shape: ', (1000,))
Loss after iteration 5: 0.959737
-----------------------------------------------------
('Train Z shape: ', (1, 200))
('Train A shape: ', (1, 200))
('Test X shape : ', (2, 200))
('Test Y shape : ', (200,))
('Test yhat shape : ', (1, 200))
(50.0, '% of test examples classified correctly.')
```

Here is my forward propagation function:

```
def f(x, w, b):  # do not change this line!
    # x is a N-by-D numpy array
    # w is a D dimensional numpy array
    # b is a scalar
    # Return three things:
    # 1) the output of the f function, as a N dimensional numpy array,
    # 2) gradient of f with respect to w,
    # 3) gradient of f with respect to b

    # Output of the f function is yHat = a = activation_function(z)
    def activation_function(z):
        global alpha
        if (z.all < 0):
            return -alpha * z
        elif (0 <= z.all <= 1):
            return (3 * z ** 3) - (4 * z ** 2) + (2 * z)
        else:
            return z

    def activation_function_prime(z, a):
        global alpha
        if (z.all < 0):
            dfdw = -alpha * x
            dfdb = -alpha
            return dfdw, dfdb
        elif (0 <= z.all <= 1):
            dfdw = (9 * np.dot(x, np.square(a))) - (8 * np.dot(x, a)) + (2 * x)
            dfdb = 9 * np.square(a) - (8 * a) + 2
            print(alpha)
            return dfdw, dfdb
        else:
            dfdw = x
            dfdb = 1
            return dfdw, dfdb

    z = np.dot(w, x) + b
    a = activation_function(z)
    dfdw, dfdb = activation_function_prime(z, a)
    print("Train Z shape: ", z.shape)
    print("Train A shape: ", a.shape)

    return a, dfdw, dfdb
```

Comment: Kinda hard to answer because the code you provide isn't the source of the error. But I can guess, maybe yhat is in an array when it shouldn't be? For example, np.array([1,2,3]) has shape (3,), whereas np.array([[1,2,3]]) has shape (1, 3). It's a common error so I thought I might throw it out there. The solution, of course, would be to do yhat = yhat[0] before predicting!

Comment: @Alan I can share my whole code with you if you're willing to help me with more details. Because my main problem is the increase in loss. And I thought it is because of the dimension change. You can reach me from my LinkedIn account mentioned on my profile. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Better to keep it to stack exchange I think. Stack overflow is excellent for answers, but you get back what you put in; the better you format the question the better your answer. Currently your question is hard to understand because you allude to the problem being first yhat dimension, then hyperparameters, then model performance. And the code you provide is not the code giving you errors! Follow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for an idea of a good question. Then myself or someone else can help.

Comment: I will follow your advices thanks.